# How to install Tensorflow GPU on Mac Mini M1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

My goal is to install Tensorflow GPU on Mac Mini M1.

The problem is, the training took 12 minutes 13.4 seconds. So I am confused whether Tensorflow is using the GPU from Apple M1.

Also there is a warning message:

```
Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-100-python.tar.gz
169001437/169001437 [==============================] - 113s 1us/step
Metal device set to: Apple M1

systemMemory: 16.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 5.33 GB

2022-11-28 13:05:11.889010: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:306] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2022-11-28 13:05:11.889173: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:272] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
Epoch 1/5
2022-11-28 13:05:13.685181: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/backend.py:5582: UserWarning: "`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received `from_logits=True`, but the `output` argument was produced by a Softmax activation and thus does not represent logits. Was this intended?
  output, from_logits = _get_logits(
2022-11-28 13:05:15.988814: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
782/782 [==============================] - 134s 156ms/step - loss: 4.7561 - accuracy: 0.0764
Epoch 2/5
782/782 [==============================] - 120s 153ms/step - loss: 4.2540 - accuracy: 0.1315
Epoch 3/5
782/782 [==============================] - 119s 153ms/step - loss: 3.9307 - accuracy: 0.1495
Epoch 4/5
782/782 [==============================] - 120s 153ms/step - loss: 3.7630 - accuracy: 0.1744
Epoch 5/5
782/782 [==============================] - 119s 153ms/step - loss: 3.3644 - accuracy: 0.2251
```

The code

```
import tensorflow as tf

cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=True,
    weights=None,
    input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
    classes=100,)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=64)
```

What I've did:

1. Install Python 3.10.8
2. `python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip`
3. `python3.10 -m pip install tensorflow-macos`
4. `python3.10 -m pip install tensorflow-metal`.

What I've not tried:

1. Install Anaconda. I have a bad experience with Anaconda and would love to avoid it.

I mentioned this because I believe the slow training time is because I did not install `tensorflow-deps` which I believe only available with `conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps`

Comment: There is no problem here, your GPU is already working.